# Ubuntu 18.04 bash: swift: команда не найдена

Tags: ubuntu, swift, bash

Через терминал выполняется без проблем, а в скрипте работать не хочет.
Вот сам скрипт:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
gnome-terminal --geometry 60x5 --hide-menubar --window -t 'GIT LOAD' -e "bash -c 'cd /home/user/Рабочий\\ стол/New_proj/; git pull origin master; swift build; sleep 5;'"
```

Comment: Скрипт запускает вручную и не работает, либо стартует через планировщик?

Comment: Скрипт запускается вручную

Comment: PATH:
/usr/share/swift/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin

Comment: В случае если указать абсолютный путь к swift ошибка повторяется, проверяли?

Comment: С абсолютным путем работает. В принципе для меня этого достаточно. Но интересно разобраться почему не работает без указания абсолютного пути. Спасибо за помощь.

Comment: Попробуйте для bash указать ключ l, т.е. `-cl`. Вероятнее всего переменная PATH сбивается при вызове новой оболочки в скрипте. к сожалению я в этом не силен, поэтому не факт.. но я надеюсь смогут сориентировать более компетентные представители сообщества в этом.

Comment: c `bash -ci` работает. Еще раз спасибо. Сам только начал изучать unix-системы

Comment: Очень фиговое начинание - юзать кириллицу и проблелы в путях. Потом нарвёшься. Отучайся.